# Obtain chunk size in split --filter commands?

Tags: linux, command-line, pipe, coreutils

I'd like to compress a partclone backup on the fly using zstd. Instead of writing one large zstd Frame, the archive should be split into small chunks that allow semi-random access. The latter requires that the uncompressed size is written to the Frame header. When feeding data to zstd from a pipe, this needs to be provided via `--stream-size` on the commandline. The following script would work if it was not for this requirement:

```sh
partclone.ntfs -c -s /dev/sda1 --output - \
    | split --bytes=2M --filter="zstd -1 --content-size --stdout" \
    > archive.zstd
```

Ideally, `split` would export an additional variable `CHUNKSIZE` which would allow

```bsh
partclone.ntfs -c -s /dev/sda1 --output - \
    | split --bytes=2M --filter="zstd -1 --stream-size=$CHUNKSIZE --content-size --stdout" \
    > archive.zstd
```

Just providing `--stream-size=2M` will produce an error on the last chunk if that is smaller. Given that the data is coming from `partclone`, reading it in chunks in a loop (which would work for raw data `dd`ed from a device) isn't possible, either. Storing an intermediate file is not an option due to performance.

Do you know of any substitute for `split` which would export the chunk size? Or any other clever trick to obtain the desired zstd invocation, short of patching `split`? Thanks!

Comment: why do you need the uncompressed size in the frame header ?

Comment: As I said, for random access, i.e. locate the frame of a zstd archive corresponding to a given offset in the uncompressed data. When a zstd file is many concatenated frames (instead of one huge frame), it is straightforward to skip over frames. However, without the uncompressed frame size, there is no way to relate compressed and uncompressed data. Ultimately, I'd like to implement an nbdkit filter similar to the xz filter, but for zstd (xz is just too slow). That would instantly allow direct, read-only mounting of zstd-compressed disk images.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/facebook/zstd/issues/412

Comment: Could you rely on the fact that all frames, except the last one, are full ?
This is effectively the case if you break input using `split`.
It would also make the jump table easier to setup, and effectively make the requirement to store uncompressed size redundant, since uncompressed size is effectively implied by the jump table.

Comment: I guess so, I'd like the uncompressed size to be stored in the first frame at least, though. Otherwise, the archive is not really self-contained for this purpose. Mostly, I was struggling to come up with a commandline that generates such an archive (since the one given in the questions exits with an error on the last chunk). I've only now encountered pzstd, which probably solves the issue, and by storing the (compressed) frame size should also speed up building a jump table.

Answer (score 0):

#### General case

Under the hood `split --filter=something …` is like many `split … | something` pipes, one at a time.

The *general* idea of piping does not include any in-advance information about the size of the stream, because:

1. A tool in a pipe often doesn't know the size of its output, until it reads the whole input and produces the output.
2. Even if it tried to pass this information to the next tool somehow, in general it could only do this at the end, i.e. after the next tool reads (almost) everything. At this moment the next tool can get the same information by simply measuring the size of its own input, so there is no point in passing this information from one tool to the next.

Pipes are designed so tools work in parallel, streaming data one to another. A tool designed to work in a pipe starts processing its input stream before the stream ends. In theory the stream may never end (e.g. `cat` should work with an eternal stream just fine). The tool should not wait for the end of the stream, unless it has a good reason (e.g. `sponge` has one).

---

#### Specific case

In your case you want to tell each `zstd` the size in advance. But for the last chunk even `split` does not know this when it starts the last `zstd`. In fact `split` cannot know which chunk is the last. It will know this only when the stream from `partclone.ntfs` ends and in general this is *after* `zstd` for the last chunk is started.

To solve your problem strictly, some kind of buffering is inevitable, unless you can tell in advance the exact size of the output from `partclone.ntfs`. If you can tell this then a (rather cumbersome and ugly) specific solution can be crafted.

---

#### Solution you won't like

> Storing an intermediate file is not an option due to performance.

To tell which chunk is the last one and what the size of it is, `split` would have to do *exactly* this. Possibly in RAM, but still. Note you (or `split`) cannot simply pass `--stream-size=2M` for all the chunks but the last one, and only use an intermediate file for the last one. Each chunk has to be buffered, because `split` does not know in advance which chunk is last. This means any performance penalty has to affect processing of all chunks, not only the last one.

Example:

```
partclone.ntfs -c -s filesystem -o - \
| split --bytes=2M --filter='
f="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"/chunk
cat > "$f"
zstd -1 --rm --stdout "$f"
' > archive.zst
```

In my case `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` expands to `/run/user/1000` which is a tmpfs large enough to additionally hold 2 MiB at a time. Adjust to your needs, especially if you ever want to use large `--bytes=`.

Note `cat`s and `zstd`s run in turns, never in parallel. If you find a way to run the next `cat` before the current `zstd` finishes, you will probably increase the performance. (Obviously in this case the next `cat` must write to another file.) *Maybe* a careful use of GNU `parallel --keep-order` *instead* of `split` can help.

---

#### Solution you may like

My tests indicate that you can append null bytes to an image created by `partclone.ntfs -c`. Then `partclone.ntfs -r` will not complain and it will be able to restore the filesystem. The result will be the same, appended null bytes won't affect it.

This means if we manage to append null bytes to the end of the stream coming from your `partclone.ntfs -c`, so each chunk is always exactly 2 MiB in size, then `--stream-size=2M` will work.

We can use `dd conv=sync` for this, but we need `iflag=fullblock` as well. `iflag=fullblock` is not portable, hopefully your `dd` supports it. This is the code:

```
partclone.ntfs -c -s filesystem -o - \
| dd bs=2M conv=sync iflag=fullblock \
| split --bytes=2M --filter='
zstd -1 --stream-size=2M --content-size --stdout
' > archive.zst
```

Without `iflag=fullblock` `dd` could inject null bytes to the stream before its end. We don't want this (compare [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/591976/108618)).

This solution adds less than 2 MiB to the end of the image compressed by `zstd`, but since these are consecutive null bytes, the tool should compress them well.

---

#### Solution I may like

I use Btrfs. Btrfs supports transparent file compression and ZSTD is one of few available algorithms. If I were you, I would store the output of `partclone.ntfs -c` in Btrfs, without modification; I would let the filesystem handle the compression. All this hassle with `split` and `zstd` is not needed then.

Only if I planned to copy between filesystems, an explicit `archive.zst` might be better. If I planned to stay within a single filesystem and it's Btrfs, I would choose the transparent compression it provides.